# Android Wear Horizontal ListView

Tags: wear-os

I'm trying to realize this layout in android wear: [Timer Custom App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEMIQ.png). I think this is like a listview with horizontal orientation, but WearableListView doesn't have this attribute.

Comment: Try RecyclerView it allows horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [GridViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridViewPager.html) and [setting negative page margins](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridViewPager.html#setPageMargins(int,%20int)) :

```
pager = (GridViewPager) stub.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
pager.setPageMargins(0, -30);
```

You can then implement onClick listeners on the fragments to change the current page by just clicking at the right or left of the page like the native alarm app.